# access this.setState inside success callback after AJAX call

Tags: reactjs

This works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"gender": "female"},
    url: "http://localhost/something.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: 

        this.setState({
            someKey: someValue
        })

})
```

This doesn't work (the function wrapper causes `this.setState` to lose the previous `this` context)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"gender": "female"},
    url: "http://localhost/something.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){     // function wrapper begins

        this.setState({
            someKey: someValue
        })
    }                       // function wrapper ends
})
```

The `this` in the second case turns out to be the `http://localhost/something.php`

What do I need to do to access the previous `this` context inside the function wrapper?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the scope for this before the function. So var self = this; and use self.setState

Comment: Try use arrow function to auto-bind the context of `this`: `success: ()=> { this.setState({someKey: someValue}) }`

Comment: @Dekel if you post as an answer I'll mark it as correct. I can't believe the arrow syntax worked! I knew that that it auto-binds the context, but I didn't expect it to work even in this situation.

Comment: @iSZ Your answer worked! I preferred Dekel's answer. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @thanks_in_advance cool no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to keep the context of the current `this` you will need to bind the callback function of the `success`.

The easiest way to do so is by using the arrow function syntax:

```
success: () => {
    this.setState({
        someKey: someValue
    })
}
```

Another option is to use a local variable to store that reference, and use that variable on the success:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {"gender": "female"},
    url: "http://localhost/something.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        that.setState({
            someKey: someValue
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call super() before accessing this, since this is not initialized until super() is called

Comment: Super has nothing to do with binding of this and only used in the constructor where you should never use ajax or any async anyway.